# View Pager With Card View

Tags: java, android

I was implementing view pager in my app, it works but only shows one element.
What if I want to show all the cards and if there is extra one goes to other page?
This is my code

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:clipToPadding="true" />
```

> onCreate

```
models=new ArrayList<>();
models.add(new ViewPagerModel(R.drawable.icon,""+getString(R.string.app_profile)));
models.add(new ViewPagerModel(R.drawable.ic_school,""+R.string.mainurl));
models.add(new ViewPagerModel(R.drawable.ic_class,""+R.string.eForm));
models.add(new ViewPagerModel(R.drawable.ic_info,""+R.string.about));
models.add(new ViewPagerModel(R.drawable.noaman,""+R.string.about_the_programmer));
adapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(models,getContext());
viewPager=view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setPadding(8,0,8,0);
```

> view pager adapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private List<ViewPagerModel> models;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(List<ViewPagerModel> models, Context context) {
        this.models = models;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,container,false);
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title;
        imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.pagerImage);
        title=view.findViewById(R.id.pagerTitle);
        imageView.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage());
        title.setText(models.get(position).getTitle());
        container.addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

> this is after running the app
> [image]

> this is how i want it
> [image]

Comment: it is "wrap_content"

Comment: Why don't you use RecyclerView?

Comment: i wanted to add indicator so i use it :(

Answer (score 0):

Evey time You are adding view  to 0 position

Replace `container.addView(view,0);`

with `container.addView(view);`

Comment: Nothing changes :(